# Sublime Text 2 HTML indent all tags

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I don't like Sublime Text 2's default indentation for HTML. I hate fact that it doesn't indent the `head` and `body` and body tags.

Specifically, when you reindent everything, it looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

..and I want it to look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-content">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...with the `head` and `body` tags one tab space in from the `html` tag.

Everytime I fix it, then write a bunch of code, then reindent, it sucks *everything* back to the left and I have to manually fix it.

I have searched all over. There are many settings in HTML.sublime-settings, but none of the deals with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can edit the settings file and change tabs to a number of spaces. I've done it previously unless I am going crazy.